# Are missing light bulbs a sign of P/meth use?

Tags: recreational-drugs

I read [this claim](http://www.nzherald.co.nz/nz/news/article.cfm?c_id=1&objectid=12000298) attributed to a landlord in Balclutha, New Zealand:

> "It's very hard to tell if a house is infected because you can't really see it. There are telltale signs for landlords, like light bulbs missing all the time. But you can't smell it or see it.''

I have a rental at the other end of the country, in Auckland, where P use is much more prevalent. One family (academics, two small kids) seemed to be getting through lightbulbs far faster than usual. Are there grounds for concern?

Comment: Absent some explanation of WHY the light bulbs would be missing, I don't see how you can give this claim much credence.

Comment: "academics, two small kids" I can think of a simpler explanation for why they're going through lightbulbs more than "usual".

Comment: @DanielRHicks The light bulbs go missing because they are turned into drug paraphernalia. From [a pertinent paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2716800/): "One IDU in Tijuana referred to the term ‘*foquemon*’ as the name for someone who smokes methamphetamine from a converted light bulb (*foco*)."

Comment: That's like saying that "getting a bit wet" is a sign of drowning. _Technically_ correct (which is, of course, the best kind of correct), but by the time the light bulbs go missing, there _should_ be other signs. I'm surprised at this landlord's claim that it's that hard to see.

Comment: Buy energy saving light globes for your rental that you can't use to smoke meth, tenants save on electricity, you save on paranoia, everybody wins! This "meth house testing" issue is overblown,  most methlabs are only discovered when they blow up.